# subtract hours in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to display the result by subtracting two-time slots into a fraction e.g 8.5 hours. At the moment I am getting the below output but I want to get 8 and if it was 8:30 for it to say 8.5. I am using Python Pandas

```
0 days 08:00:00
```

`start time example: 8:00:00`
`finish time example: 16:30:00`

```
  g=file.start[0]
  h=file.finish[0]
  z=h-g
  print(z)
```

currentOutput

```
0 days 08:00:00
```

Comment: z.dt.total_seconds()/3600

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.timedelta`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html) on your current output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

(pd.to_datetime('16:30:00')-pd.to_datetime('8:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1,'h')
# 8.5
```

**EDIT**: or, you can replace `np.timedelta64` with `pd.TimeDelta` (so you don't need to import `numpy`):

```
(pd.to_datetime('16:30:00')-pd.to_datetime('8:00:00')) / pd.Timedelta(1,'h')
```

Comment: Personal preference `(pd.to_timedelta('16:30:00') - pd.to_timedelta('8:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1,'h')`

Comment: That works too. Any particular reason you prefer that? Subtracting 2 `Timedeltas` or 2 `datetimes` both end up in a `Timedelta`

Answer (score 1):

If `z` is a `timedelta` object (see [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)), then you just need to do:

```
print(z.total_seconds() / 3600)
```

to get the time in hours.

Comment: the seconds attribute is how many seconds modulus 1 Day.  That means 8.5 Hours and 32.5 Hours will have the same seconds value.  You want `total_seconds()`